# Comparison between two different merge sort implementations explained

Tags: python, complexity-theory, mergesort

I wrote my implementation like this:

```py
def merge_sort(lst):
    if len(lst) < 2: return lst

    midx = len(lst) // 2

    return merge(
        merge_sort(lst[:midx]),
        merge_sort(lst[midx:])
    )

def merge(left, right):
    merged_lst = []
    while left and right:
        merged_lst.append((left.pop(0) if left[0] <= right[0] else right.pop(0)))

    merged_lst.extend(left if left else right)
    return merged_lst
```

Then I found this one online:

```py
def mergeSort(alist):
    if len(alist)>1:
        mid = len(alist)//2
        lefthalf = alist[:mid]
        righthalf = alist[mid:]

        mergeSort(lefthalf)
        mergeSort(righthalf)

        i=0
        j=0
        k=0
        while i < len(lefthalf) and j < len(righthalf):
            if lefthalf[i] <= righthalf[j]:
                alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
                i=i+1
            else:
                alist[k]=righthalf[j]
                j=j+1
            k=k+1

        while i < len(lefthalf):
            alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
            i=i+1
            k=k+1

        while j < len(righthalf):
            alist[k]=righthalf[j]
            j=j+1
            k=k+1
```

I thought mine would be faster, but use up more memory. Then I profiled both for `med_lst` and `big_lst`:

```py
med_lst = [random.random() for _ in range(100000)]
big_lst = [random.random() for _ in range(500000)]
```

Using code structured like this in Jupyter notebook:

```py
printmd(f'RAM at start: {memory_profiler.memory_usage()[0]:0.1f}MiB', color='blue')
t1 = time.time()
printmd(f'Sorting: {len(big_lst)} elements', color="blue")
merge_sort(big_lst)
t2 = time.time()
printmd(f'RAM after sorting list: {memory_profiler.memory_usage()[0]:0.1f}MiB, took {t2 - t1:0.1f}s', color='blue')
```

The time complexities surprised me:

Medium List:
`merge_sort`: 1.2s
`mergeSort`: 0.6s

Big List:
`merge_sort`: 29.0s
`mergeSort`: 3.4s

Is this meant to be just because of creating a new list, and maybe collisions or resizing? Or is my implementation / thought process wrong (rookie error - 0 points for this answer)? I think my function is still `0(nlogn)`, but as the collection gets larger can you really say they're "comparable"

I didn't get into profiling this line by line because it's meant to be more fundamental

Comment: Popping from index 0 is O(*n*), see [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Comment: Your version creates hell a lot of lists and constantly appends/pops lists. Changing size of objects in memory is never fast. The second version is done in place, so it's pure computing, no waiting for memory to be ready

Comment: @AlexLarionov Second is *not* in place.

Comment: @superbrain @AlexLarinov I think that comment was just referring to the ending inside the `merge`

Comment: @superbrain, yes my mistake, just was looking at the code, forgetting how merge sort actually works

Comment: Why show us that memory_profiler code but not its output?

Comment: @CH. right popping from beginning and shifting is not a good move

Comment: @superbrain shared the code just in case. didn't share the output because I was just using it for learning to see if anything surprising happens - the output itself is not necessarily valid. But it said mine took up like 2MiB more in space

Comment: sorry this: `if left: left.reverse(); if right: right.reverse(); while left and right: merged_lst.append((left.pop() if left[-1] <= right[-1] else right.pop())); if left: left.reverse();
if right: right.reverse(); merged_lst.extend(left if left else right)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by @CH, the `pop()` from the front came out to be the culprit.

By making a small change to reverse the lists before popping and then reversing back after, I managed to make my implementation actually faster than the other one:

```py
def merge(left, right):
    merged_lst = []
    if left: left.reverse()
    if right: right.reverse()
    while left and right:
        merged_lst.append((left.pop() if left[-1] <= right[-1] else right.pop()))
    if left: left.reverse()
    if right: right.reverse()
    merged_lst.extend(left if left else right)
    return merged_lst
```

Medium List: `merge_sort`: 0.5s `mergeSort`: 0.7s

Big List: `merge_sort`: 2.6s `mergeSort`: 4.0s